# Failed to install PostgreSQL with OpenSSL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build PostgreSQL 16.2 with openssl to install pgcrypto extension. I use mac os big sur 11.7.10 version. I downloaded source from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v16.2.

`openssl version -a` output:

```
OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024)
built on: Tue Jan 30 13:28:16 2024 UTC
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: clang -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl@3.0"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3.0/3.0.13/lib/engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3.0/3.0.13/lib/ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: OPENSSL_ia32cap=0x7ffaf3ffffebffff:0x27ab
```

`configure` command executes successfully:

```
./configure --prefix=$APPS_DIR/postgresql-16.2 --with-zlib --with-ssl=openssl --with-includes=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/include --with-libraries=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/lib
```

at the end I will append `config.log` file content. I got error running `make world`, the latest lines are:

```
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2 -pthread -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -I. -I../../../src/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/include -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk   -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/include -I../../../src/port -I../../../src/port -DSO_MAJOR_VERSION=5  -c -o fe-connect.o fe-connect.c
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2 -pthread -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -I. -I../../../src/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/include -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk   -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/include -I../../../src/port -I../../../src/port -DSO_MAJOR_VERSION=5  -c -o fe-misc.o fe-misc.c
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2 -pthread -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -dynamiclib -install_name '/Users/savenkodenys/apps/postgresql-16.2/lib/libpq.5.dylib' -compatibility_version 5 -current_version 5.16 -exported_symbols_list exports.list -o libpq.5.dylib  fe-auth-scram.o fe-connect.o fe-exec.o fe-lobj.o fe-misc.o fe-print.o fe-protocol3.o fe-secure.o fe-trace.o legacy-pqsignal.o libpq-events.o pqexpbuffer.o fe-auth.o fe-secure-common.o fe-secure-openssl.o -L../../../src/port -L../../../src/common -lpgcommon_shlib -lpgport_shlib -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk   -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs   -lssl -lcrypto -lm  
duplicate symbol '_PQsslStruct' in:
    fe-secure.o
    fe-secure-openssl.o
duplicate symbol '_PQsslAttributeNames' in:
    fe-secure.o
    fe-secure-openssl.o
duplicate symbol '_PQgetssl' in:
    fe-secure.o
    fe-secure-openssl.o
duplicate symbol '_PQsslAttribute' in:
    fe-secure.o
    fe-secure-openssl.o
duplicate symbol '_PQdefaultSSLKeyPassHook_OpenSSL' in:
    fe-secure.o
    fe-secure-openssl.o
duplicate symbol '_PQsetSSLKeyPassHook_OpenSSL' in:
    fe-secure.o
    fe-secure-openssl.o
duplicate symbol '_PQgetSSLKeyPassHook_OpenSSL' in:
    fe-secure.o
    fe-secure-openssl.o
ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [libpq.5.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-libpq-recurse] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-interfaces-recurse] Error 2
make: *** [world-src-recurse] Error 2
```

A bit of `config.log` file content:

```
## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='ar'
AWK='awk'
BISON='/usr/bin/bison'
BISONFLAGS=''
BITCODE_CFLAGS=' -O2 '
BITCODE_CXXFLAGS=' -O2 '
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS='-Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2'
CFLAGS_CRC='-msse4.2'
CFLAGS_SL=''
CFLAGS_SL_MODULE=' -fvisibility=hidden'
CFLAGS_UNROLL_LOOPS=' -funroll-loops'
CFLAGS_VECTORIZE=' -ftree-vectorize'
CLANG=''
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS='-isysroot $(PG_SYSROOT)   -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/include'
CXX='g++'
CXXFLAGS='-Wall -Wpointer-arith -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -O2'
CXXFLAGS_SL_MODULE=' -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden'
DBTOEPUB=''
DEFS='-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
DLSUFFIX='.dylib'
DTRACE=''
DTRACEFLAGS=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
FLEX='/usr/bin/flex'
FLEXFLAGS=''
FOP=''
GCC='yes'
GCOV=''
GENHTML=''
GREP='/usr/bin/grep'
ICU_CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/include'
ICU_LIBS='-L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata'
INCLUDES=' -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/include'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LCOV=''
LDAP_LIBS_BE=''
LDAP_LIBS_FE=''
LDFLAGS='-isysroot $(PG_SYSROOT)   -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'
LDFLAGS_EX=''
LDFLAGS_EX_BE=''
LDFLAGS_SL=''
LIBOBJS=' ${LIBOBJDIR}explicit_bzero$U.o ${LIBOBJDIR}pthread_barrier_wait$U.o'
LIBS='-lssl -lcrypto -lz -lreadline -lm '
LLVM_BINPATH=''
LLVM_CFLAGS=''
LLVM_CONFIG=''
LLVM_CPPFLAGS=''
LLVM_CXXFLAGS=''
LLVM_LIBS=''
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=' ${LIBOBJDIR}explicit_bzero$U.lo ${LIBOBJDIR}pthread_barrier_wait$U.lo'
LZ4='/usr/local/bin/lz4'
LZ4_CFLAGS=''
LZ4_LIBS=''
MKDIR_P='\${SHELL} \${top_srcdir}/config/install-sh -c -d'
MSGFMT=''
MSGFMT_FLAGS=''
MSGMERGE=''
OBJEXT='o'
OPENSSL='/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/bin/openssl'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='PostgreSQL'
PACKAGE_STRING='PostgreSQL 16.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='postgresql'
PACKAGE_URL='https://www.postgresql.org/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='16.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL='/usr/bin/perl'
PERMIT_DECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT='-Wno-declaration-after-statement'
PG_CRC32C_OBJS='pg_crc32c_sse42.o pg_crc32c_sb8.o pg_crc32c_sse42_choose.o'
PG_MAJORVERSION='16'
PG_SYSROOT='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk'
PG_VERSION_NUM='160002'
PKG_CONFIG='/usr/local/bin/pkg-config'
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig'
PORTNAME='darwin'
PROVE=''
PTHREAD_CC='gcc'
PTHREAD_CFLAGS='-pthread -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE'
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
PYTHON=''
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP='strip -x'
STRIP_SHARED_LIB='strip -x'
STRIP_STATIC_LIB='strip -x'
SUN_STUDIO_CC='no'
TAR='/usr/bin/tar'
TAS=''
TCLSH=''
TCL_CONFIG_SH=''
TCL_INCLUDE_SPEC=''
TCL_LIBS=''
TCL_LIB_SPEC=''
TCL_SHARED_BUILD=''
UUID_LIBS=''
WANTED_LANGUAGES=''
WINDRES=''
XGETTEXT=''
XML2_CFLAGS=''
XML2_CONFIG=''
XML2_LIBS=''
XMLLINT='/usr/bin/xmllint'
XSLTPROC='/usr/bin/xsltproc'
ZIC=''
ZSTD='/usr/local/bin/zstd'
ZSTD_CFLAGS=''
ZSTD_LIBS=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
autodepend=''
ax_pthread_config=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin20.6.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
default_port='5432'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_coverage='no'
enable_debug='no'
enable_dtrace='no'
enable_nls='no'
enable_rpath='yes'
enable_tap_tests='no'
enable_thread_safety='yes'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin20.6.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_bin='/usr/bin/install -c'
krb_srvtab=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
perl_archlibexp=''
perl_embed_ccflags=''
perl_embed_ldflags=''
perl_includespec=''
perl_privlibexp=''
perl_useshrplib=''
prefix='/Users/savenkodenys/apps/postgresql-16.2'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
python_additional_libs=''
python_includespec=''
python_libdir=''
python_libspec=''
python_majorversion=''
python_version=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
vpath_build='no'
with_gssapi='no'
with_icu='yes'
with_krb_srvnam='postgres'
with_ldap='no'
with_libxml='no'
with_libxslt='no'
with_llvm='no'
with_lz4='no'
with_perl='no'
with_python='no'
with_readline='yes'
with_selinux='no'
with_ssl='openssl'
with_system_tzdata=''
with_systemd='no'
with_tcl='no'
with_uuid='no'
with_zlib='yes'
with_zstd='no'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "PostgreSQL"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "postgresql"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "16.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "PostgreSQL 16.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.postgresql.org/"
#define CONFIGURE_ARGS " '--prefix=/Users/savenkodenys/apps/postgresql-16.2' '--with-zlib' '--with-ssl=openssl' '--with-includes=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/include' '--with-libraries=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.0/lib' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig'"
#define PG_MAJORVERSION "16"
#define PG_MAJORVERSION_NUM 16
#define PG_MINORVERSION_NUM 2
#define PG_VERSION "16.2"
#define DEF_PGPORT 5432
#define DEF_PGPORT_STR "5432"
#define BLCKSZ 8192
#define RELSEG_SIZE 131072
#define XLOG_BLCKSZ 8192
#define HAVE_VISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE 1
#define DLSUFFIX ".dylib"
#define ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY 1
#define USE_ICU 1
#define PG_KRB_SRVNAM "postgres"
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT 1
#define HAVE_PTHREAD 1
#define HAVE_STRERROR_R 1
#define STRERROR_R_INT 1
#define HAVE_LIBM 1
#define HAVE_LIBREADLINE 1
#define HAVE_LIBZ 1
#define HAVE_SPINLOCKS 1
#define HAVE_ATOMICS 1
#define OPENSSL_API_COMPAT 0x10001000L
#define HAVE_LIBCRYPTO 1
#define HAVE_LIBSSL 1
#define HAVE_X509_GET_SIGNATURE_NID 1
#define HAVE_SSL_CTX_SET_CERT_CB 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_INIT_SSL 1
#define HAVE_BIO_METH_NEW 1
#define HAVE_ASN1_STRING_GET0_DATA 1
#define HAVE_HMAC_CTX_NEW 1
#define HAVE_HMAC_CTX_FREE 1
#define HAVE_X509_GET_SIGNATURE_INFO 1
#define USE_OPENSSL 1
#define HAVE__BOOL 1
#define HAVE_STDBOOL_H 1
#define HAVE_COPYFILE_H 1
#define HAVE_EXECINFO_H 1
#define HAVE_GETOPT_H 1
#define HAVE_IFADDRS_H 1
#define HAVE_LANGINFO_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_EVENT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_UCRED_H 1
#define HAVE_TERMIOS_H 1
#define HAVE_READLINE_READLINE_H 1
#define HAVE_READLINE_HISTORY_H 1
#define PG_PRINTF_ATTRIBUTE printf
#define HAVE__STATIC_ASSERT 1
#define HAVE_TYPEOF 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_TYPES_COMPATIBLE_P 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_CONSTANT_P 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_UNREACHABLE 1
#define HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTO 1
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE 1
#define HAVE_UNION_SEMUN 1
#define HAVE_SOCKLEN_T 1
#define HAVE_STRUCT_SOCKADDR_SA_LEN 1
#define HAVE_LOCALE_T 1
#define LOCALE_T_IN_XLOCALE 1
#define restrict __restrict
#define pg_restrict __restrict
#define HAVE_STRUCT_OPTION 1
#define HAVE_X86_64_POPCNTQ 1
#define SIZEOF_OFF_T 8
#define SIZEOF_BOOL 1
#define PG_USE_STDBOOL 1
#define HAVE_INT_TIMEZONE 1
#define WCSTOMBS_L_IN_XLOCALE 1
#define HAVE_BACKTRACE_SYMBOLS 1
#define HAVE_COPYFILE 1
#define HAVE_GETIFADDRS 1
#define HAVE_INET_PTON 1
#define HAVE_KQUEUE 1
#define HAVE_MBSTOWCS_L 1
#define HAVE_MEMSET_S 1
#define HAVE_PTHREAD_IS_THREADED_NP 1
#define HAVE_STRSIGNAL 1
#define HAVE_USELOCALE 1
#define HAVE_WCSTOMBS_L 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_BSWAP16 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_BSWAP32 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_BSWAP64 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_CLZ 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_CTZ 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_POPCOUNT 1
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_FRAME_ADDRESS 1
#define HAVE_FSEEKO 1
#define HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE 0
#define HAVE_DECL_FDATASYNC 0
#define HAVE_DECL_STRLCAT 1
#define HAVE_DECL_STRLCPY 1
#define HAVE_DECL_STRNLEN 1
#define HAVE_DECL_PREADV 1
#define HAVE_DECL_PWRITEV 1
#define HAVE_DECL_F_FULLFSYNC 1
#define HAVE_GETOPT 1
#define HAVE_GETPEEREID 1
#define HAVE_INET_ATON 1
#define HAVE_MKDTEMP 1
#define HAVE_STRLCAT 1
#define HAVE_STRLCPY 1
#define HAVE_STRNLEN 1
#define HAVE_GETOPT_LONG 1
#define HAVE_SYSLOG 1
#define HAVE_INT_OPTERR 1
#define HAVE_INT_OPTRESET 1
#define HAVE_HISTORY_TRUNCATE_FILE 1
#define HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES 1
#define HAVE_RL_FILENAME_COMPLETION_FUNCTION 1
#define HAVE_RL_VARIABLE_BIND 1
#define HAVE_LONG_INT_64 1
#define PG_INT64_TYPE long int
#define INT64_MODIFIER "l"
#define HAVE__BUILTIN_OP_OVERFLOW 1
#define SIZEOF_VOID_P 8
#define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
#define SIZEOF_LONG 8
#define ALIGNOF_SHORT 2
#define ALIGNOF_INT 4
#define ALIGNOF_LONG 8
#define ALIGNOF_DOUBLE 8
#define MAXIMUM_ALIGNOF 8
#define PG_INT128_TYPE __int128
#define ALIGNOF_PG_INT128_TYPE 16
#define HAVE_GCC__SYNC_CHAR_TAS 1
#define HAVE_GCC__SYNC_INT32_TAS 1
#define HAVE_GCC__SYNC_INT32_CAS 1
#define HAVE_GCC__SYNC_INT64_CAS 1
#define HAVE_GCC__ATOMIC_INT32_CAS 1
#define HAVE_GCC__ATOMIC_INT64_CAS 1
#define HAVE__GET_CPUID 1
#define USE_SSE42_CRC32C_WITH_RUNTIME_CHECK 1
#define USE_SYSV_SEMAPHORES 1
#define USE_SYSV_SHARED_MEMORY 1
#define MEMSET_LOOP_LIMIT 1024
#define PG_VERSION_STR "PostgreSQL 16.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11), 64-bit"
#define PG_VERSION_NUM 160002

configure: exit 0
```